# How to set image resource in Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am writing code for a poker game on eclipse and I am stuck on how to make the card clicked in the `cardHand` area show up in the `playedCards` area and have it removed from the deck I am drawing it from.  Here's the code:

```
package com.viktorengineering.poker254;

import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.Random;

public class Poker extends Activity {
    private ImageView mViewDeck;
    private ImageView mViewHand;
    private ImageView mViewPlayedCards;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.green_back);

        mViewDeck = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deckImage);
        mViewDeck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int[] imagesArray = {R.drawable.clubs_ace, R.drawable.hearts_seven, R.drawable.diamonds_five,
                        R.drawable.clubs_three, R.drawable.hearts_eight, R.drawable.spades_six};
                Random random = new Random();
                mViewHand.setImageResource(imagesArray[new Random().nextInt(6)]);
            }
        });
        mViewHand = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardHand);
        mViewHand.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewPlayedCards.setImageResource(0);
                mViewHand.setImageResource(0);
            }
        });
        mViewPlayedCards = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playedCards);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Image in Drawable Folder means use bellow code

mViewPlayedCards.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
 mViewHand.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_home);